# The provided issuer certificate does not have an associated private key

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, x509certificate, ecdsa

I'm trying to write a method for creating a certificate which is not CA certificate using the RequestCertificate class and method Create.
I've used this code, it created additional CA but I don't need it because I already have one:

```
public static void CreateCertificate4(string username, string password)
{
    var ecdsa = ECDsa.Create(); // generate asymmetric key pair
       
    var r = new CertificateRequest("cn=" + username, ecdsa, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);
                
    var cert = r.CreateSelfSigned(DateTimeOffset.Now, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddYears(5));
    var cert = proba.Create(certCA, DateTimeOffset.Now, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddYears(2), Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password));

    string path1 = (AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\" + username + ".pfx");
    string path2 = (AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\" + username + ".cer");

    // Create PFX (PKCS #12) with private key            
    File.WriteAllBytes(path1, cert.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, password));

    // Create Base 64 encoded CER (public key only)
    File.WriteAllText(path2,
        "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\r\n"
        + Convert.ToBase64String(cert.Export(X509ContentType.Cert), Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks)
        + "\r\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----");
}
```

I've tried to modify it and came up with this:

```
public static void CreateCertificate(string username, string password)
{
    var certCA = GetCertificateFromStorage(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine, "TestCA");

    var ecdsa = ECDsa.Create(); 

    var proba = new CertificateRequest("cn=" + username, ecdsa, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);

    var cert = proba.Create(certCA, DateTimeOffset.Now, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddYears(2), Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password));       
               
    string path1 = (AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\"+username+".pfx");
    string path2 = (AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\"+username+".cer");

    File.WriteAllBytes(path1, cert.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, password));

    // Create Base 64 encoded CER (public key only)
    File.WriteAllText(path2,
        "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\r\n"
        + Convert.ToBase64String(cert.Export(X509ContentType.Cert), Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks)
        + "\r\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----");
}
```

There is an error in line:
`var cert = proba.Create(certCA, DateTimeOffset.Now, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddYears(2), Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password));`  as stated in the title.

Comment: The method CertificateRequest() did not find the certificate.

Comment: @jdweng CertificateRequest is a class.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.certificaterequest?view=net-6.0

Comment: Still the class must contain the certificate.  The code is calling the constructor method.

Comment: As exception says, signing certificate does not have associated private key to sign your certificate.

Comment: Non-CA certificates are signed by the private key belonging to the CA certificate, in this case `certCA`. So that variable points to a certificate for which the private key is not available or not associated with the certificate in `certCA`. Maybe you stored the previously generated root certificate and its private key (I hope you secured that anyway) and only retrieved the certificate afterwards.